# Reopen windows when logging back in feature in arch

Tags: arch-linux, mate-desktop, macos

I am planning to shift from mac to linux (arch mate most likely) but there is one feature that I particularly like in macOS and that is the option to "reopen windows when logging back in".

I checked out various web pages and ended up something named save-session option in dconf-editor but also found out that even that is not applicable for all OS plus not recommended for daily use either.

I use a portable SDD which has all my OS (in different partition) and thus I cannot use hibernate feature. I just want to know whether such software even exist or is it unique to macOS. And please let me know if there is any software/or way available for any linux so that I get the session back as I left after I restart my OS.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is built-in to MATE. Got to System -> Preferences -> Look&Feel -> Windows and than tick the box:

[image]